# How to resolve include file names conflicts in GCC?

Tags: c, gcc, header-files

I have two header files named `string.h` in different libraries, they are conflicted with each other and even conflicted with standard C include file of the same name.

There is no need to use any `string.h` except standard one, but I need to include libraries headers paths in GCC search path. Currently I use something like `-I /usr/local/include/lib1 -I /usr/local/include/lib2`, but that way I can not include standard C `string.h`.

What is the right way to resolve such conflicts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can probably use `#include <lib1/string.h>` and compile with `gcc -I/usr/local/include`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that directories added to the search path via -I get looked up before the standard ones which for gcc are (in order)

```
/usr/local/include/
/usr/include/
/usr/local/lib/
/usr/lib/
```

So you can follow Schnouki's advice, except that there is no need to add -I/usr/local/include

Comment: "The problem is that directories added to the search path via -I get looked up before..."  <- Can you provide a reference explaining this?  I am trying to find it but haven't been successful yet..  [Ok, I found some info here: https://devdocs.io/gcc~12/directory-options ]