# How to handle header name conflicts?

Tags: c, header, include, wrapper

How to handle name conflicts when including headers?

E.G.:

```
#include "config.h" // from lib a
#include "config.h" // from lib b
```

I now I can handle name conflicts with types and functions, if I write a wrapper... but how to handle such a conflict? Is there a way to write a wrapper for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to get over this problem is to include the full file path between the quotes.

Something like

```
#include "/liba/inc/config.h"
```

Also, you didn't specify what compilier you are using, but here's a thread that deals with this exact same problem with GCC: [How to resolve include file names conflicts in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665979/how-to-resolve-include-file-names-conflicts-in-gcc)

Comment: Relative paths, such as `liba/inc/config.h`, would usually be preferred, since these permit adapting to a change of location simply by changing a compiler option (the header search path) rather than editing sources.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from using explicit paths to the header files, you might also consider *not* exposing both headers in the same source file. For example, you would create `b_config_provider.h` and `b_config_provider.c`. `b_config_provider.c` would include `config.h` from library `b` and would provide a wrapper around those facilities (with wrapping API exposed in `b_config_provider.h`). This is clearly somewhat involved but it minimizes potential conflicts  (as well as *future* conflicts).